# Rails 3.0.5 Nested Form - Unable to Create New - WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm having difficulty saving two fields in a nested form. The parent field saves fine, but the nested field is throwing the "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes" error.

I've placed things in the Item model with attr_accessible, but it's not solving the issue.

## List_controller

```
def create
  @list = List.new(params[:list])
  @list[:user_id] = current_user.id
  if @list.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created list."
    redirect_to @list
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

## List model

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? },     :allow_destroy => true
end
```

## Item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

## Form

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |list_form| %>

  <p>
    <%= list_form.label :title %><br />
    <%= list_form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= render :partial => 'item_fields',
         :locals => {:form => list_form} %>
  </p>

  <%= list_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## Form partial

```
<%= form.fields_for :item do |item_form| %>
    <%= item_form.label :name, 'item' %>
    <%= item_form.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

## Server error log

```
Started POST "/lists" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Mar 27 02:54:18 -0400 2011
  Processing by ListsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create List", "list"=>{"title"=>"figaro", "item"=>{"na
me"=>"foobar"}}, "authenticity_token"=>"afu5xPgvJenu6XKXcsyilR8RconLP/OZ3NxsICE3RVk=
", "utf8"=>"Γ£ô"}
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."i
d" = 2 LIMIT 1


WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: item


  ←[1m←[36mAREL (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO "lists" ("user_id", "updated_at", "
title", "created_at") VALUES (2, '2011-03-27 06:54:18.893302', 'figaro', '2011-0
3-27 06:54:18.893302')←[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/lists/77
Completed 302 Found in 117ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `fields_for :item` but your `List` model `has_many :items`.

Try this:

```
<%= form.fields_for :items do |item_form| %>
```

If this doesn't help try to add `attr_accessible :items_attributes` to you `List` model. From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

> [..] If you are using attr_protected or attr_accessible, then you will need to add the attribute writer to the allowed list.

Comment: Thanks, I kept trying to add variations into the Item model, but I'm supposed to add it to the List model

Answer (score 0):

Add `attr_accessible :items` to your List class.